# Showing Related Data In A DataGridView

Tags: .net, datagridview, controls

If anyone's used Access recently, you might recall that when it displays data for a table that has a relationship, a little expandable node appears next to each row. Clicking on it shows all of the data from other tables related to that row in-line, underneath the row.

I basically want to do that in .Net. Is this something I can do using a DataGridView, which I'm already using, or do I need to build/buy something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DataGridView from .NET 2.0+ doesn't show child records like Access.  However, the .NET 1.x DataGrid control does.  You can use this in your project.

You may also wish to check this out:
[Customizing the DataGridView to support expanding/collapsing (ala TreeGridView)](http://blogs.msdn.com/markrideout/archive/2006/01/08/510700.aspx)

Edit:  One thing I'll add.  When I was investigating this issue for a .NET 2.0 application I was writing I was going to use a .NET 1.1 DataGrid for this functionality.  I also looked into alternatives (like the component I linked above) but in the end decided not to complicate things and went with two DataGridViews linked in a master-detail relationship.

[How to: Create a Master/Detail Form Using Two Windows Forms DataGridView Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c12c1kx4(VS.80).aspx)